Traverse A Quarternary Tree iteratively
I learned about traversing Binary Search Trees both recursively and iteratively. For the iterative approach to the inorder traversal of a BST I used a stack to keep track of the nodes, go until the left-most node, pop from the stack and then go into the right subtree. Now I want to iteratively traverse a quaternary tree. This tree has up to 3 key values and up to 4 children nodes. I tried applying the same stack logic that I used for the BST to the Quarternary Tree but wasn't successful. Any ideas for the general logic of traversing it with an iterative approach? Thanks in advance!

Your stack has to include a lot more state: which of the children and which of the keys have been traversed.

Can you provide the code you have tried with, also including the data structure, and the initialisation of a non-trivial example tree?

I guess you are no longer interested in your question...
